# Internet in android application is not working in case of Bluetooth Tethering

Tags: android, bluetooth, android-manifest, tethering

Internet in my Android Application is working in case of *Wifi* and *Mobile Data*. But when it comes to *Bluetooth Tethering*, its not working. What can be the possible reason/solution for that?

I have used the following permissions so far:-

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE"/>
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.bidloc.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
```

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Which Android os used for testing?